# Screen record lags on MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, catalina, screen-capture, video-capture

Recently I've been trying to record the screen of my Mac. I would like to record some video games and coding projects that I have made but I could not find any way to record the screen without lag.

I have tried some programs but they all lag. Therefore I decided to move to OBS but even tweaking many options I could not find a way to not have a laggy recording.

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 and I think it is just not made to do these type of things.

Any good software suggestions?

Comment: Since you're asking for a software recommendation you may want to read [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation)

Comment: "Lag" is inevitable. You're trying to run a game at full speed whilst simultaneously capturing the screen **and** saving that result to disk. That's going to need a fast computer, not a laptop.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin this is ultimately what I was wondering myself.